# My translation is full of weird characters?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm populating a **GridView** with translations of a particular phrase in various languages obtained via web requests to **Google Translate**.

[image]

I already am using `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` to take care of special characters (e.g. umlauts, accents), but what's the deal with the diamond question marks?

Comment: You're trying to load characters that are not available in your character set.

Comment: I thought Google was shutting down their Translate service API?

Comment: @Korvin: Should I be using a different font in my browser (e.g. one that supports unicode)?

Comment: @Mark: They are I believe as of December of 2011, but this is an http request outside of their API (e.g. http://www.google.com/translate_t?hl=en&ie=UTF8&text={0}&langpair={1} as if I were talking to Google Translate via browser).

Comment: @DarthContinent, all you need do is define your encoding: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#h-5.2

Comment: @Korvin: I have UTF-8 encoding specified in my document as a meta tag: <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">

Comment: @DarthContinent It's most likely a game of finding the right encoding for your locale =\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is Google Translate I believe - they're using a special encoding that isn't supported directly by .NET. It's an ISO encoding and those characters when downloaded via WebClient/WebRequest result in errors because it doesn't know what to do with the encoding.

I had the same issue and I ended up using their Google Translate's JSON API to get clean characters returned.

Post here:
http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2011/Aug/06/Translating-with-Google-Translate-without-API-and-C-Code

Hoe this helps,

+++ Rick ---

Comment: This did help, once I applied "webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Mozilla/5.0");" to my WebClient instance, the funky characters now appear as expected.